# How to calculate the residue of the function: $ f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{e^z+e^{-z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, singularity

How would one find the residue of the following function:

$$ f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{e^z+e^{-z}}$$

I tried finding the poles of the function by setting $e^z+e^{-z} = 0 $ and then deducing that  the poles are:

$$z_0 = \frac{\pi i}{2}(1+2k)$$ for integers k.

However, I am unsure how to find the residue given these poles.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They are simple poles. Do you know a formula for the residue at a  simple pole?

Comment: yes, i would multiply it by $(z-z_0) $and then take the limit  as z goes to the pole but wsomehow i dont get the correct\sensible answetr

Comment: You are correct, and I even got that in my answer. Will delete comment. @GEdgar

Answer (score 1):

If $g(z)=e^z+e^{-z}$ then $g(z_0)=0$ and we can compute the limit:

$$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\tag{1}$$

and invert the result to get the limit:

$$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{z-z_0}{g(z)-g(z_0)}$$

But then you can just multiply by $e^{iz_0}$ to get the residue.

Finally, (1) is just the derivative of $g(z)$ at $z_0,$ by definition.

So the residue at $z_0=\frac{\pi i }2(2k+1)$ is:

$$\frac{e^{iz_0}}{e^{z_0}-e^{-z_0}}=\frac{e^{-\frac \pi2(2k+1)}}{(-1)^k2i}$$

This wouldn’t work if $g$ had a double zero at $z_0$ - that is, if $g(z_0)=g’(z_0)=0.$